# image and its name mismatch after read images from TFRecords file

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I write two methods using TensorFlow:

- `convert_imgs_to_TFRecords`, coverts all images in `./dataset` to TFRecords file `img.tfrecords`
- `read_imgs_from_TFRecords`, reads the `img.tfrecords`, get `image`s and their information, including `height`, `weight`, `channel` and `name`.

But the images mismatch their names.

For example, A image named `001.jpg` and B image named `002.jpg` are converted to `img.tfrecords`, but A image get name `002.jpg` and B image get `001.jpg` after `read_imgs_from_TFRecords`.

The two methods as follows:

```
def convert_imgs_to_TFRecords(imgs_dir='./dataset', tfrecords_name='img.tfrecords'):

    img_filenames_list = os.listdir(imgs_dir)

    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecords_name)

    for item in img_filenames_list:
        file_extension = item.split('.')[-1]
        if(file_extension == 'jpg'):
            img_filename = os.path.join('./dataset', item)
            print("writing {0}".format(item))
            img = cv2.imread(img_filename)# uint8 dtype
            rows = img.shape[0]
            cols = img.shape[1]
            channels = img.shape[2]
            example = tf.train.Example(features = tf.train.Features(feature={
                'name': _bytes_feature(item.encode('utf-8')), # str to bytes
                'height': _int64_feature(rows),
                'width': _int64_feature(cols),
                'channel': _int64_feature(channels),
                'img': _bytes_feature(img.tostring())
                }))
            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
```

and

```
def read_imgs_from_TFRecords(tfrecords_file='./img.tfrecords'):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(string_tensor=[tfrecords_file], 
                                                num_epochs=None, 
                                                shuffle=False, 
                                                seed=None, 
                                                capacity=32, 
                                                shared_name=None, 
                                                name=None, 
                                                cancel_op=None)
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features={
        'name': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'channel': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'img': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
            })    
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['img'], tf.uint8)
    # normalize
    # normalize_op = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) * (1.0/255) - 0.5

    height = features['height']
    width = features['width']
    channel = features['channel']
    name = features['name']
    print("ready to run session")
    init_op = tf.group(tf.local_variables_initializer(), 
                   tf.global_variables_initializer())
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
        for i in range(22):
            img = image.eval()
            h, w, c = [height.eval(), width.eval(), channel.eval()]
            title = name.eval()
            title = title.decode()#bytes to str
            img = img.reshape([h, w, c])
            # pil_image = Image.fromarray(img)
            # pil_image.show()
            print('showing ' + title)
            cv2.imwrite(title, img)
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: It seems that your `img`, `h`, `w`, `c`, `title` all refer to different samples. I can't confirm this fr sure because I can't run your code, but I am fairly certain that one call to `sess.run()` (which is what internally the `eval()` does) reads one item from the input and returns the value of the tensor for that specific run. Try doing `img, h, w, c, title = sess.run([ image, height, width, channel, name ])` and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: Also, you should really consider [giving the Dataset API a try, it simplifies input pipelines massively](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets)

Comment: you should group all the pieces of an single example to a single sess.run like sess.run([height, width, image])

Answer (score 1):

As Gphilo and Jie.Zhou said in the comment, we should group all the pieces of an single example to an single sess.run.
So, I correct

```
img = image.eval()
h, w, c = [height.eval(), width.eval(), channel.eval()]
title = name.eval()
```

to

```
img, h, w, c, title = sess.run([image, height, width, channel, name])
```

The two methods are just trying tf.TFRecord, and one should better use [Datasets API](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) in your project.